# Material emissivity coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

If I have a coated material (e.g. oxidized steel painted with white paint) which emissivity coefficient do I use ? The one of the paint (0.3-0.5) or the one of the base material (0.8) ? Many collegues go and paint a spot with a black marker and then use ε=1. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Heat passes between the steel and the paint by conduction, which is typically much faster than radiation. The limiting factor is the radiation at the object:air interface i.e. you need the emissivity of the surface at the object:air interface.

So the emissivity you need is the emissivity of the paint.

This also explains why your colleagues are correct to use a high emissivity once they've painted the steel black.